# How can I define vertices of a plane that is always parallel to the camera?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to draw a rectangle (basically a plane) that is always parallel to the camera. I want to restrict plane to a certain size (lets say height = 2 and width = 2 units). However, I do not understand  how to set position to the vertices such that rectangle will always be parallel to the camera.

First I am calculating camera normal (direction) using:

```
glm::normalize(mPosition - mTargetPos); // normal
```

and then I am using  point-normal equation to define the plane:

```
normal = (A, B, C)
point = (a, b, c)  // this point will serve as a center to the plane
A(x−a)+B(y−b)+C(z−c) = 0
```

Question: How can I define vertices of the plane?

Answer (score 0):

1. Take some normilized vector `UpDir` for up direction (it can be `UpDir=(0,1,0)` or `UpDir=(0,0,1)` depending on your coordinate system, or it can be computed somehow)
2. Compute cross product `SideDir` of the `normal` and the `UpDir`.
3. Now you can use the `SideDir` and `UpDir` as basis for your plane's coordinate system, and compute four vertices of the rectangle as `point+width*SideDir+height*UpDir`, `point+width*SideDir-height*UpDir`, `point-width*SideDir-height*UpDir`, `point-width*SideDir+height*UpDir`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to define the points in view space. Finally transform the points by the [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) view matrix.
In view space the points are parallel to the view if they have the same z coordinate. The z-coordinate has to be negative and its amount has to greater than the distance to the near plane and less than the distance to the far plane:

```
near < -z < far
```

Compute the view matrix (`view_mat`) and define the points in view sapce:

```cpp
glm::mat4 view_mat = glm::lookAt(mPosition, mTargetPos, mUp);
float z = 

glm::vec3 pt1View(x1, y1, z);
glm::vec3 pt2View(x2, y2, z);
// [...]
```

Transform the points from view space to world space:

```cpp
glm::mat4 inverse_view_mat = glm::inverse(view_mat);

glm::vec3 pt1World = glm::vec3(inverse_view_mat * glm::vec4(pt1View, 1.0f));
glm::vec3 pt2World = glm::vec3(inverse_view_mat * glm::vec4(pt2View, 1.0f));
// [...]
```